# Trying to change text in cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't used VBA in Excel in a decade but wanted to find a coding solution to changing a bunch of text in over 20K cells. My job has me doing it manually, but I know there has to be a Comp Sci solution.

I've sorted the column that I need to change. And there are thousands of duplicates that need to be changed such as the below example shows

Example: 1001.tif changed to 1001_1.tif if it is the first duplicate or leave it if it's the first text of that value.

My code below doesn't work at all but should be the framework to it.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  Dim n As Integer
    n = 1
  Dim test As String
    test = Cells(1, D).Text
  Dim active As String
    active = Cells(2, D).Text

  For i = 2 To 12
    active = Cells(i, D)
      If active = test Then
        Cells(i, D).Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(test, 4) + "_" + n + ".tif"
        n = n + 1
    Else
        test = active
    End If
Next i

Cells(1, a).Text = "Done"

End Sub
```

Any tips?

Comment: use `.Value2` instead of `.Text`

Comment: Thank you but, I tried it and it still gives me the same Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Have a look at the answers below. You need to change more then just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have some aversion to vba, here is an implementation as an in-cell formula of the same approach as a current vba answer. Assuming that D is the column of filenames:

=IF(COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2) > 1, MID(D2, 1, FIND(".", D2) - 1) & "_" & COUNTIF($D$2:D2, D2) & ".tif", D2) will do the same.

Some explanation:
The COUNTIF() formula counts the number of occurrences of a string from the top of the column ($D$2) to the current row.
The MID/FIND formula puts the number of occurrences and an underscore in the place before the . in the filename. FIND gets the place of the ., MID cuts the string off right before the dot, then the rest of the formula appends the number and file extension. This will work for numbers longer than 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIF():

```
Sub Button1_click()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
For i = 2 To 12
    With ActiveSheet
        j = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(i - 1, 4)), Left(.Cells(i, 4), Len(.Cells(i, 4)) - 4) & "*")
        If j > 0 Then
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = Replace(.Cells(i, 4), ".tif", "_" & j & ".tif")
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Turns this:

[image]

Into:

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do but I get a Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.  when I click debug it highlights the line for j = Application

Comment: Are you using Excel or Visual Studios?

Comment: I'm using excel 2016

Comment: Then it should work.  Not sure why it would not work for you.  Did you change any of the code from what I have?

Comment: No i didn't however my test data was a different length but I changed it to match the 4 digits and the ext- and it worked but still with the error though. 
Would I have to change the code to handle a longer file name?

Comment: Yes, When dealing with strings it is never easy.  Try to figure ti out.  If you are unable to get it to work, ask a new question and make sure to include examples that cover all outliers.

Comment: Great thank you. Yeah I want to figurew this out because going through 20,000 lines of file names is super annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the changes I've made below. I think this is what you're trying to accomplish.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim test As String, active As String

    n = 1

    For i = 2 To 12
        active = Cells(i, D).Value2
        If active = test Then
            Cells(i, "D").Value2 = Left(test, 4) & "_" & n & ".tif"
            n = n + 1
        Else
            test = active
        End If
    Next i

    Cells(1, "A").Value2 = "Done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your code, based on assumptions of what you meant to do. Hopefully this'll be of help.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  Dim n As Integer
  Dim test As String
  Dim active As String

  n = 1

  For i = 2 To 12
      active = Cells(i, 4)
      test = Cells(i - 1, 4)
      If active = test Then
          Cells(i, 4).Value = VBA.Left(test, 4) & "_" & n & ".tif"
          n = n + 1
      Else
          test = active
          n = 1
      End If
  Next i

  Cells(1, 1).Value = "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: The issue with this code is in the beginning of the loop the reset of test to equal the row above active will be tested against so  it would output 1001.tif 1001_1.tif 1001.tif.  Thank you though. The resetting of n is the else statement was definitely something I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

This code will do as you described. Just sort all the files that are identical and run the macro. I added rg to count rows that are used to be dynamic, but you can change it to your needs.

```
  Sub test()
  Dim n As Integer
  Dim rg As Integer
  rg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    n = 1
  Dim test As String
    test = Cells(1, 4).Text
  Dim active As String

  For i = 2 To rg
    active = Cells(i, 4)
      If active = test Then
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Left(test, 4) & "_" & n & ".tif"
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next i

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```